# having internal storage problem

Tags: internal-storage

After rooting my lollipop5.0 with kingroot then after some time my internal storage became zero, I cannot install any app,please if anyone has a solution please help me out:

[image: user apps page] [image: system apps page]
<sup>User apps / system apps (click images for larger variants)</sup>

Also storage is not visible from the storage page in settings,it shows only calculating:

[image: disk usage] [image: DiskUsage]
<sup>Storage and DiskUsage (click images for larger variants)</sup>

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use an app like [DiskUsage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage) to see what is occupying space and delete uneeded stuff

Comment: I checked it I have a lot of free space,but my issue is that my internal storage has become zero,in the system application manger page,it shows the size of every app as 0.0,please help me

Comment: Please post screen shots of the app showing disk usage and app manager page by editing your question

Comment: If anyone has any solution please help me

Comment: It would be great if you could paste result of "mount" command. If you have Terminal installed, just type "mount". If not, enable USB debugging, install Google USB Driver on your PC, install ADB on your PC, connect your phone with USB, accept new PC on phone, open adb folder in cmd.exe, then type "adb shell mount"

Comment: What do you think the problem is?

Comment: Is it understandable or should I join them